# How to debug the "Installation failed" error in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

When trying to run the application in Android Studio, I'm getting the following error message:

[image]

Unfortunately, there is no further information about the cause of the error.

Is it possible to get more detailed information?

Comment: maybe open help menu -> show log in finder

Comment: What happens if you build an APK file and install it via `adb  install`? Does that work and if not what error message do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer.

In Android Studio Iguana 2023.2.1 on Macos, select Help -> Show Log in Finder after the failed installation and open the `idea.log` file.

Search for `Error running 'app':<br>The application could not be installed.` - the full stack trace will be present there. Some helpful information can be found above the stacktrace.